# When Tracking Google Analytics across Payment Domains, what tracking is needed?

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, payment-gateway, web-analytics, universal-analytics

I have used referral exclusion list, but I'm more interested in getting the coding setup correctly once, rather than using referral exclusion list hundreds of times (we have loads of referrers in our payment gateway). We have many referrers because depending on which bank the visitor's card is, they will be sent to a different domain.

Do you need to set tracking on the content which sends the user to a domain you dont own, then add something on the domain that you do own?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain is accomplished by using `linker`, which is [part of the UA package](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain)

> The analytics.js library uses a single first-party cookie to store the Client ID that can only be accessed by the domain on which it is set. If you own multiple domains and would like to track users across them, additional work must be done so that the analytics.js cookie data is maintained across each of those domains.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
If I get hundreds of referrals from various banks, what is the best way to capture all of them as non-referrals (and return them from 'Referral', to their original Medium).
I read somewhere that you are supposed to add tracking to a link which will send a user to a domain which isnt yours, then link them on the other end, but I cant remember what I read and was hoping someone here would know :|

Comment: Sadly there's nothing in the API for this. Google's only remedy is to [exclude it in the account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you have a website A that will send traffic to multiple payment portal (Paypal, banks etc.) and then send traffic back to a thank you page.

You can't set up tracking on Paypal/banks using the linker commmand, as you don't have access to the domains, but you can setup Paypal/banks to send users to a thank you page where you can record e-commerce info.

If the user will complete their session under 30 mins, you can tell that thankyou page to ignore referrals from Paypal/Banks, so the users will instead keep their referral data from when they first hit your website (say search)

It depends a little what version of the GA tracking code you are using - if its _gaq you can use [_addIgnoreRef()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addIgnoredRef) to your thank you page.

If its UA, then after a [look through the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) there doesn't seem to be an equivalent tag wise, instead relying on the ignore referrer list in the interface which you've tried, but (untested) what may work is to set the referrals for the thank you page to be direct, in which case GA attributes to the previous campaign.

This would look like:

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', '(direct)');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', '(direct)');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', '(direct)');
```

Comment: My company uses Paypal, but if a user selects a bank, instead of PayPal, then there are almost limitless domains (I've already excluded 130, paypal being one of them). If someone pays by bank card, they go off to their own bank's domain (which isnt paypal). Thats how I can get hundreds of different referrers.

Comment: Ok, I'll add an edit.  If you can send them all to the same thank you page afterwards then you an turn off referrers for just that page.

Comment: But this looks like a case where it was easier with the older GA code! The UA code is a untested.